# mysql join, need suggestion

Tags: mysql

I have created a MySQL table with a foreign key value. I want to use MySQL join to fetch foreign key value. 
I have a table called `employee` and foreign key value `sex`, Sex table contain Male & Female.
this is my simple join query which is working:

```
SELECT * FROM sex JOIN employee ON employee.sex_id=sex.id
```

but i want to use join query here, but it seems I am missing some thing, Please complete this:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, sex_id FROM employee
```

And please tell me how i will `insert to` forigen key in single query for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `employee_employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `maritial_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sex_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_employee` (`employee_employee_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_address1` (`address_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_phone1` (`phone_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_maritial1` (`maritial_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_sex1` (`sex_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I have not good idea in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT emp.employee_id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name, emp.sex_id, sx.sex_label 
FROM employee AS emp
JOIN sex AS sx
ON emp.sex_id = sx.id
```

Where sex_label is a field name in `sex` table that would contain either Male or Female.

Comment: Its working fine. please also need help regarding `insert` employee table

Comment: Yes please put your question.

Comment: i want to INSERT TO a table which contain foreign relationship. Like table `employee` (table structure in my question),

Comment: This link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php will help you to save associated data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, s.id
FROM employee AS e
JOIN sex AS s
ON e.sex_id = s.id
```

Comment: but its showing only the ID of sex not its value, how to show the value of sex table?